# Data save to Event i get Push key . But issue while Event_key assign EventList { ref : Event_key } Firebase Real Time Database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I saved some of data under **event** and that Location/Key i required for user reference. So i had tryed to save user/eventlist { ref : Event_Key }. But I got error then concatenate with string even-though I got a error.

Console out Put

```
OnSumit Working
Postjobc.js:11 getLocation Working
Postjobc.js:47 Fist Condition Ok : undefined
Postjobc.js:68 0
Postjobc.js:23 Eventinsert Working :-MF0_ZKTuNdiN0QbIjbd    (I get key )
Postjobc.js:18 position Working
logger.ts:115 [2020-08-18T12:41:19.218Z]
@firebase/database:
FIREBASE WARNING: set at /users/userId/eventlist/-MF0_berJy7yKkaZvS-G failed: permission_denied
```

Firebase rules

```
"rules": {
"users": {
  "$uid": {
    ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
    ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
          }
        },
"jobpost":{
  "events":{
    ".read" : "auth.uid != null",
     ".write": "auth.uid != null"
  }
```

Real Time Database

```
-https://Project.firebaseio.com/celebrity_program/
   -events

             -MppF9d5aIkhia2u5kka  (Event_key)
    -user   
       -$uid
         
           -eventList
                -Mdhhshhsheuer 
                    eventref : Event_Key
```

Case 1

```
const Eventinsert = () => {
    var EventsId = Firebase.database().ref('events/').push({
        Title: Title,
        Role: Role,
        Location: Location,
        Description: Description,
        SelectionBy: SelectionBy
    })

    var str = EventsId.key;
    var loo = true;
    do {
        if (typeof str !== undefined) {
            console.log(str);                [console output val= -MErnwYwknRZz5MFH ]     
            EventListInsert(str);
            loo = false;
        }
    } while(loo)
  } 

  EventListInsert (Key){
      console.log(key);           [console output : key =-MErnwYwknRZz5MFH ]
        var userId = localStorage.getItem("User");    
         var d = new Date();
        Firebase.database().ref('user/UserId/eventlist/').push({
           event: key,
            latitude: la,
            longitude: lo,
            date: d
      })
     }

  }
```

I got error as **"Error: Reference.push failed: first argument contains undefined in property 'eventlist.event"**

Case 2

```
const Eventinsert = () => {
    var EventsId = Firebase.database().ref('events/').push({
        Title: Title,
        Role: Role,
        Location: Location,
        Description: Description,
        SelectionBy: SelectionBy
    })

    var str = EventsId.key;
    var loo = true;
    do {
        if (typeof str !== undefined) {
            var val= "str" + str;
            console.log(val);                [console output val= str-MErnwYwknRZz5MFH ]     
            EventListInsert(val);
            loo = false;
        }
    } while(loo)
  }
  var userId = localStorage.getItem("User");
  function EventListInsert ( Key ){
      var d = new Date();
        Firebase.database().ref('user/UserId/eventlist/').push({
          
            event: Key,
            latitude: la,
            longitude: lo,
            date: d
      })
     }
```

I gotsame  error as **"Error: Reference.push failed: first argument contains undefined in property 'eventlist.event"**

But  if i remove  **event: Key,** It run successful  the Event_List add to database.
The user required to have ref what post I'm ?
How to resolve this . Are any other way to ref ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error indicates that the `event` property could be undefined. `typeof str !== undefined` does not determine whether the string is undefined. It would be better to just test it as whether `str` is not falsy using `if(str)` instead.

Comment: I had test str get key Using console.log(str) in EventList () . I got key.

Comment: OnSumit Working
Postjobc.js:11 getLocation Working
Postjobc.js:47 Fist Condition Ok : undefined
Postjobc.js:68 0
Postjobc.js:23 insert Working :-MF0_ZKTuNdiN0QbIjbd
Postjobc.js:18 position Working
logger.ts:115 [2020-08-18T12:41:19.218Z]  @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: set at /users/userId/eventlist/-MF0_berJy7yKkaZvS-G failed: permission_denied